# Is there any way to detect if the live stream is started successfully in JITSI meet external API?

Tags: live-streaming, jitsi, jitsi-meet

I am using the jitsi meet external API to make video conference.

I use the following API command to start live streaming:
`api.executeCommand('startRecording', { mode: 'stream', youtubeStreamKey: streamName })`

But is always returns undefined, is there any way to identify if the streaming is started successfully or not.